# How can I remove an addCallback?

Tags: actionscript-3, addcallback

I have a Flash game which send and receive lot of messages from JavaScript.
Sometimes I need to stop listening some of those functions, but ExternalInterface doesn't have a removeCallback function. So I'm doing somthing ugly: using a boolean to validate if a callback is available in each function.

Any better solution?

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("callAlert", callAlert);
function callAlert(msg:String){
   if(callAlertAvailable){
      //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call again addCallback, setting the function as null:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("callAlert", null);
```

Why not read the docs? I found it here:
[ExternalInterface.addCallback()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29)

> Note: Repeating addCallback() on an existing callback function with a
>   null closure value removes the callback.

Comment: Note: this doesn't actually works very well, when callback wasn't added yet - calling to the method from JS shows "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when it was removed with the methods above - it will show "Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.". So it doesn't work very clean.

Comment: I've try to remove it with this code, but error has appear when web calls removed event: [Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_callIn()